# TempData Cookie Issue. The size of the request headers is too long

Tags: session, asp.net-core, cookies, tempdata

In **Controller**, I save a collection of errors into `cookies` via `TempData`

```
var messages = new List<Message>();
...
TempData.Put("Errors", messages);
```

TempData.Put is an extension method

```
public static class TempDataExtensions
    {

        public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
        {
            tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
        {
            tempData.TryGetValue(key, out object o);
            return o == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
        }
    }
```

When HTML is loaded, I see

[image]

and several cookies were created (Chrome Developer Tools > Application > Storage > Cookies)

[image]

The issue I think, is that total size of Cookies is hitting some Cookie Size limit somewhere.

So I have two questions :
Is it possible to change the cookie size limit (in web.config for example) ?
Is it possible to use session instead of cookies for `TempData` ?

I tried the second approach and if I change the **startup.cs** file

```
\\ ConfigureServices method

services.AddMvc()
   .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
   .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

services.AddSession();

\\ Configure method

app.UseSession();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute(
     name: "default",
     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

The TempData are still using Cookies, do I forgot some setting somewhere ?

Comment: As you mentioned, normally if we need to store large amounts of data in TempData, we can use the [session provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-the-tempdata-provider) instead.  Besides, after you enabled session-based TempData provider, please try to clear existing cookies using browser F12 developer tool then browse your site to check if it work well.

Comment: Hello Han, how can I be assured, that session provider works ? The cookies are still being created, therefore I posted this question.

Comment: Yes you can use Session based temp data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use HTTP cookies or session state as storage mechanism for `TempData`. The cookie-based `TempData` provider is the default.
You can read more about [Choose a TempData provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#choose-a-tempdata-provider).

Based on the following example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#configure-the-tempdata-provider) you can enable the session-based `TempData` provider, by calling [`AddSessionStateTempDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcviewfeaturesmvcbuilderextensions.addsessionstatetempdataprovider?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) extension method. The [order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#order) of middleware is important.

> Be aware of `DefaultTempDataSerializer` limitations pointed out at
> bottom of this answer.

**Example**

Hers is [a working deployment](https://tempdatasessionexample.azurewebsites.net/) using the following setup that I have for **Srartup**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { Configuration = configuration; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddSession();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

The **HomeController**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["LargeData"] = new string('a', 1 * 1024 * 1024);
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the **Index** View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome - @(((string)TempData["LargeData"]).Length)</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">
       building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

### DefaultTempDataSerializer supported types

Be aware of [`DefaultTempDataSerializer`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c39fbb8f12002f61df6c093b0c11e6bd585ee202/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Infrastructure/DefaultTempDataSerializer.cs) supported type limitations:

```
public override bool CanSerializeType(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    }

    type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;

    return
        type.IsEnum ||
        type == typeof(int) ||
        type == typeof(string) ||
        type == typeof(bool) ||
        type == typeof(DateTime) ||
        type == typeof(Guid) ||
        typeof(ICollection<int>).IsAssignableFrom(type) ||
        typeof(ICollection<string>).IsAssignableFrom(type) ||
        typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

Comment: Reza, thank you, I have it as you. On localhost it works, but after publishing to IIS it throw error 400, what now ? :/

Comment: Which Version of ASP.NET CORE are you using?

Comment: version 2.1 and compability version is also CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1. I verified that no cookies are generated when using localhost IIS, but after switch to development IIS, it still uses CookieTempProvider.

Comment: Updated the answer with a working solution and a working deployment. Also be aware of DefaultTempDataSerializer supported type limitations.

Comment: It works ! I put ashes on my head, because I also had `services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();` in the `startup.cs` which negated session settings. I don't understand that I didn't notice it earlier.

Comment: Oops! You should have copied the code into a clean project. Anyway, the good thing is your problem has been solved. Thanks for the feedback :)